# Continuity of $f:x \rightarrow ||x||_{\beta}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$||.||_{\beta}$ denotes any vector norm. How does one show that $f:x \rightarrow ||x||_{\beta}$ is continuous w.r.t the $||.||_1$ norm?

Comment: On a finite dimensional space, this is a quick consequence of the fact that all norms are comparable. On an infinite dimensional space, this is false.

Comment: Whats this quick "consequence" for finite dimensional space?

Comment: Since you're working with a normed space it is enough to show that $f$ is sequentially continuous, i.e. show that if $x_n\rightarrow x$ for some sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then $||x_n||_\beta\rightarrow ||x||_{\beta}$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Ok, but is this w.r.t the $||.||_1$ norm?

Comment: Ah yes I should have been more precise. When you assume that $x_n\rightarrow x$ it should be with respect to the $||\cdot||_{1}$ norm, i.e. $||x_n-x||_1\rightarrow 0$.